# What kind of proxy do I need to setup to access a constantly changing DNS entry? (forward or reverse)

Tags: proxy

A vendor of mine recently switched to akamaiedge.net. I have an internal server whose default route does not leave my network. For the last 15 years, I have had a static route in place for a the static IP of my vendor which sends all traffic through my Internet gateway.

Last week, my vendor switched to akamaiedge.net which changes the IP of the DNS lookup every few minutes. This is breaking my internal application. It would be next to impossible to keep up with a whitelist of all akamaiedge IPs.

I think I need to setup a proxy server internally that is allowed to talk to the WAN. My idea is that I could setup a host table entry for the FQDN of my vendor and always return the IP of my proxy server. Then, let the proxy server handle dealing with changing IPs. Ideally, I would want the proxy server to be transparent to my application.

Is this possible?

Comment: Upon further searching, it appears that what I'm looking for is called a "transparent proxy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, you should deploy reverse proxy. There is two solutions, both of them suitable for you. First one - [setup `HAProxy`](https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/installation-steps-ha-proxy-as-reverse-proxy/2169/5), second one - [setup `nginx`](https://linuxize.com/post/nginx-reverse-proxy/). Choose better for you. I prefer to use `nginx`.

Comment: There are a lot more Reverse Proxy solutions available than just those two. Traefik and IIS are two more popular reverse proxy options.